# Is there any HessianKit Sample project?

Tags: web-services, ipad, ios, hessian

I found the hessian/hessiankit for iphone very interesting and i am thinking of using it for this new project im working on that's targeting ipad.

i just couldnt find any sample complete project written in objective C that demonstrates the use of hessianKit for iphone.

Also i was wondering if its still supported in the latest 4.2 SDK of ios.

I would really appreciate any help guys.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a little off, as it seems to be mostly in Chinese, but it contains all the ingredients for iOS side:

http://blog.163.com/gshexianghui@126/blog/static/2815332520113632316391/

I hope to post some sample code of my own soon.